# How to debug AJAX Calls with Safari?

Tags: ajax, debugging, safari, xmlhttprequest

I need to **debug** the **AJAX-Call** (XHR) in Safari-Browser. I found the Developer-Console, but not the part where i can see the Ajax-Calls, like with Chrome where it is under Network.

Can someone show me the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to debug AJAX-Calls (XHR) in Safari.

1. You need to get the **Develop menu item**

   - In the **Safari** Menu Click **Preferences**
   - In the **Advanced Tab** enable **Show Develop menu in menu bar**

Now you got the **Develop** Menu Item in the top-bar.

2. On the page, where you want to debug ajax,

   - Click the **Develop** Menu Item
   - Click **Show Web Inspector** or just use the keyboard shortcut: **Option** + **Command** + **I**
3. In the Web Inspector

   - Click the **Network Tab**
   - In the left-bottom corner Click **All Resources**
4. Send your ajax call (e.g. clicking button or link)

   - Now you find something like: **index.php** in the left window
   - If you double-click on this

## You got your Debug / the ajax result in a new tab ;)

---

**EDIT:**

I made a mistake. That was the reason, why i didn't get an ajax-call in the Network-Tab:

Behind the **gear-symbol** on the right side of the **Web Inspector** you can configure this option: **Show Scope Chain on pause**.

Because of this, the Call was paused, and i got no ajax-load.

Comment: Sorry to bump an ancient thread, but is there really no way to see the XHR activity in the `CONSOLE` tab??!  It's extremely useful to have `About to 'POST'` logs interleaved with the actual `POST '/api/fnord'` messages — which can then expand to include the Request/Response payloads — rather than having to bounce back and forth between disparate tabs...  :-(